# Displaying a DateTime in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, view, model, asp.net-mvc-5.2

So, there seem to be many similar questions on this topic, but after trying everything I can, either I am missing something, or they are out of date (I am using MVC 5.2).

**Model**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

**CSHTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DOB, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result**
(Yes, I checked that there is data in the DOB object)

[image: DOB Field Image]

Where am I going wrong here? Why does the data not show?

Thanks.

Comment: `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (must be ISO format)

Comment: Well that's stupid, but working now. (I thought I had tried that too)